# Using Workflows In Powershell

Tags: powershell, parallel-processing, powershell-5.0

I have been using just a standard `foreach` loop, which executes as it should.  However, I have an 8 core processor and 16GB of RAM and thought I would utilize such with a `Parallel.foreach` loop.  Well, this syntax works as it should

```
$filelist = Get-ChildItem G:\GoodFilesForServer\ -filter *.mkv
$num = $filelist | measure
$filecount = $num.count 
$i = 0;
ForEach ($file in $filelist)
{
    $Workflow:i++;
    $oldfile = $file.DirectoryName + "\" + $file.BaseName + $file.Extension;
    $newfile = $file.DirectoryName + "\" + $file.BaseName + ".mp4";      
    $progress = ($Workflow:i / $filecount) * 100
    $progress = [Math]::Round($progress,2)
    Clear-Host
    Write-Host -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Write-Host Handbrake Batch Encoding
    Write-Host "Processing - $oldfile"
    Write-Host "File $Workflow:i of $filecount - $progress%"
    Write-Host -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Start-Process "C:\Program Files\HandBrake\HandBrakeCLI.exe" -ArgumentList "-i `"$oldfile`" -t 1 --angle 1 -c 1 -o `"$newfile`" -f mp4  -O  --decomb --modulus 16 -e x264 -q 32 --vfr -a 1 -E lame -6 dpl2 -R Auto -B 48 -D 0 --gain 0 --audio-fallback ffac3 --x264-preset=veryslow  --x264-profile=high  --x264-tune=`"animation`"  --h264-level=`"4.1`"  --verbose=0" -Wait -NoNewWindow
    del $oldfile
}
```

Simple enough, but it is not `Parallel` this syntax does not work, and no error is shown to help me determine why it does not work.

```
Workflow ParallelTest
{
  $filelist = Get-ChildItem G:\GoodFilesForServer\ -filter *.mkv
  $num = $filelist | measure
  $filecount = $num.count 
  $i = 0;
  ForEach -Parallel -ThrottleLimit 20 ($file in $filelist)
  {
    $Workflow:i++;
    $oldfile = $file.DirectoryName + "\" + $file.BaseName + $file.Extension;
    $newfile = $file.DirectoryName + "\" + $file.BaseName + ".mp4";      
    $progress = ($Workflow:i / $filecount) * 100
    $progress = [Math]::Round($progress,2)
    Clear-Host
    Write-Host -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Write-Host Handbrake Batch Encoding
    Write-Host "Processing - $oldfile"
    Write-Host "File $Workflow:i of $filecount - $progress%"
    Write-Host -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Start-Process "C:\Program Files\HandBrake\HandBrakeCLI.exe" -ArgumentList "-i `"$oldfile`" -t 1 --angle 1 -c 1 -o `"$newfile`" -f mp4  -O  --decomb --modulus 16 -e x264 -q 32 --vfr -a 1 -E lame -6 dpl2 -R Auto -B 48 -D 0 --gain 0 --audio-fallback ffac3 --x264-preset=veryslow  --x264-profile=high  --x264-tune=`"animation`"  --h264-level=`"4.1`"  --verbose=0" -Wait -NoNewWindow
    del $oldfile
  }
}
```

What should I alter in my `Workflow` syntax in order to be able to run the conversion in `Parallel` (btw, if a `ThrottleLimit` of 20 is insane to try, we can decrease that)

Comment: you surely can't `write-host` inside a workflow without an InlineScript. what happens if you delete all `x-host` from your workflow?

Comment: @SimonS - if I delete all the write-host lines, still nothing appears to takes place.  For example, in my powershell window when code was executing it would hang on the PS C:\Users\Me line, but when I execute this, there is no delay it immediately writes the syntax to the window and a new C:\Users\Me line is shown (which is what happens when the code has completed execution)

Comment: hmm... are you loading the workflow into the cache first and then call it by executing `ParallelTest`? a workflow behaves like a function so it needs to be loaded into the cache first and then called.

Comment: @SimonS - I am not sure what you mean by "Loading the workflow into the cache" but I am calling it by using ParallelTest

Comment: you are executing your whole `workflow parallelTest { #stuff }` (this is the loading into cache) and then you're executing `ParallelTest` (call the workflow). that's what I mean. Just to be sure.

Comment: Ah, yes that is exactly how I am executing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42121/discussion-between-simons-and-user2676140).